# puppet suppress cron resource message with manifest

Tags: puppet

When I configure a cron through puppet its printing the below message on crontab file,

```
# HEADER: This file was autogenerated at <date> by puppet.
# HEADER: While it can still be managed manually, it is definitely not recommended.
# HEADER: Note particularly that the comments starting with 'Puppet Name' should
# HEADER: not be deleted, as doing so could cause duplicate cron jobs.
```

Is there anyway to suppress this message?

Comment: Not unless you do a resource afterward to remove those lines.

Comment: Thats ok. If possible atleast I can suppress that message for new servers

Comment: @MattSchuchard you sure about that? pretty sure if you use puppet's builtin cron resource it will display that message. and doing a resource afterwards will get you into a loop which defeat's puppet's idempotent nature,

Comment: @ptierno I didn't say it was a good idea, just that it was possible. Probably one of the reasons I did that as a comment and not an answer.